# Invalid Procedure Call or Argument on IsError & InStr

Tags: vba, excel

I'm hoping someone can help with the error I am receiving?

I am trying to look up a value within a cell with a lot of text. I am Trying to find the text `"TOTAL DDD AMOUNT"` within a cell and then return the value

(Note - `Range("P1458")` is a sample cell that I know the value exists and should return a value).

```
Dim ValDDDRng As Range
Set ValDDDRng = Worksheets("DATA2").Range("P1458")
Dim ValDDD As Variant

If Not IsError(Mid(ValDDDRng, InStr(1, ValDDDRng, "TOTAL DDD AMOUNT", _ 
     vbTextCompare) + 17, (InStr(1, ValDDDRng, ",", vbTextCompare)) _
     - (InStr(1, ValDDDRng, "TOTAL DDD AMOUNT", vbTextCompare)))) Then
```

Example of the text within the cell that it is looking for these values. Sometimes the start may include additional text so it is not consistent of where in the cell the Amount may be. I am looking to return the value `75.33` but first clarify that there is no error whilse getting the value. If the `IsError` returns an error then it is to return a Nothing but Else return the actual value (From the example £75.33)

> **** TAXES: 58.99 GBR,TOTAL DDD AMOUNT: 75.33 GBR,TOTAL FEES: 16.34 GBR,** BLUE/GREEN**,FILE RECORD PREPARED,*****CLEARED DDD*****

When I run the If Not IsError example I am receiving an Invalid Procedure Call or Argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to finding the first numeric value after `"TOTAL DDD AMOUNT"`, is divided to 2 parts.

**Part 1**: use `Instr` function to find the position of `"TOTAL DDD AMOUNT"` string inside the cell.

```
xPos = InStr(1, ValDDDRng, "TOTAL DDD AMOUNT", vbTextCompare) '<-- result is 23
```

**Part 2**: use `RegEx` object to get the first numeric result (in any format with decimal values), by looking at only at the Cell's text, starting from `"TOTAL DDD AMOUNT"`, by using `Reg.Execute(Mid(ValDDDRng, xPos))`.

In your example, `Mid(ValDDDRng, xPos)` = "TOTAL DDD AMOUNT: 75.33 GBR,TOTAL FEES: 16.34 GBR,** BLUE/GREEN**,FILE RECORD PREPARED,*****CLEARED DDD*****"

**Code**

```
Dim ValDDDRng As Range
Dim ValDDD As Variant, xPos As Long

' RegEx variables
Dim Reg As Object
Dim RegMatches As Variant, Match As Variant

Set ValDDDRng = Worksheets("DATA2").Range("P1458")

xPos = InStr(1, ValDDDRng, "TOTAL DDD AMOUNT", vbTextCompare)

Set Reg = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With Reg
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = "(\d+)(?:\.(\d{1,2}))?" ' Match number (with decimals)
End With

Set RegMatches = Reg.Execute(Mid(ValDDDRng, xPos))
If RegMatches.Count >= 1 Then ' make sure there is at least 1 match
     ValDDD = RegMatches(0) ' <-- this is the numeric value you are looking for
End If
```

Comment: Perfect thank you. This the first time I have used RegEx so I will do a bit of reading on this. I have added 1 addition to clarify that TOTAL DDD AMOUNT Exists before the Set Reg Matches as when the cell was blank or didn't contain this text then an error appeared.

Comment: Hi @ShaiRado I'm hoping you can help I have read up on RegEx and I'm confused by the Pattern I am trying the same issue but I will return a value of 11/13 to look for the date. Am I correct in thinking amending the pattern to the following would work? '"(\d+)(?:\/(\d{1,2}))?"'

Comment: @AlanTreanor you can use the site: https://regex101.com/r/sUOCSd/3 to test `RegEx`

Answer (score 2):

Your original code is throwing that error because there is a comma before `TOTAL DDD AMOUNT`

This means that you are trying to pass a negative number to the `Mid`
command.

This is much easier to see if you split up your command into different stages:

```
Sub original()

Dim ValDDDRng As Range
Set ValDDDRng = Worksheets("DATA2").Range("P1458")
Dim ValDDD As Variant

Dim totalPos, commaPos As Integer
Dim total As String
Dim totalSearch As String

  totalSearch = "TOTAL DDD AMOUNT"
  totalPos = InStr(1, ValDDDRng, totalSearch, vbTextCompare)
  commaPos = InStr(1, ValDDDRng, ",", vbTextCompare)

  total = Mid(ValDDDRng, totalPos + 17, commaPos - totalPos) ' commaPos - totalPos is negative!
  If Not IsError(total) Then
    MsgBox "Total is " & total
  Else
    MsgBox "Is error"
  End If
End Sub
```

The following snippet locates the comma after the `TOTAL DDd AMOUNT` and then locates `75.33 GBR`

```
Sub improved()

Dim ValDDDRng As Range
Set ValDDDRng = Worksheets("DATA2").Range("P1458")
Dim ValDDD As Variant

Dim totalPos, commaPos As Integer
Dim total As String
Dim totalSearch As String

  totalSearch = "TOTAL DDD AMOUNT"
  totalPos = InStr(1, ValDDDRng, totalSearch, vbTextCompare)
  commaPos = InStr(totalPos, ValDDDRng, ",", vbTextCompare) ' need to find the second comma

  total = Mid(ValDDDRng, totalPos + 17, commaPos - totalPos - Len(totalSearch) - 1)
  If Not IsError(total) Then
    MsgBox "Total is " & total
  Else
    MsgBox "Is error"
  End If
End Sub
```

All that said, using Regular Expressions as per Shai Rado's answer is a much neater solution and less brittle when it comes to different input text. I just wanted to show you where the error was coming from and how to re-arrange your code for easier debugging

Comment: Thank you It looks much tidier spreading this out instead of trying to combine to one code.